# Эмуляция событий мыши без перемещения курсора

Tags: vb.net

Возможно ли выполнять события мыши в указанных координатах, не перемещая в это время курсор в место события?

Сейчас задействованы

```
SetCursorPos
GetCursorPos
mouse_event
```

Пытался использовать `SendMessage`, вешая на хандл, но ничего не происходит.

Что можете посоветовать?

Comment: Формулировка очень... странная. Я распарсил "как можно в WinAPI сэмулировать событие мыши в точке, отличной от той, где она находится сейчас". Оно? Рекомендую отредактировать вопрос и немножко его переформулировать, потому что в таком виде многие пройдут мимо него.

Comment: Хлебом не корми, дай потроллить?.. Заголовок сформулирован абсолютно понятно!

Comment: Заголовок более-менее, вопрос нет, сбивает с толку. Если вы считаете, что в вопросе всё в порядке, можете не редактировать. Я советую принимать меры, которые увеличат шансы получить ответ на вопрос. Не хотите -- дело ваше.

Comment: PostMessage прямо в нужное окно, или под-окна, зависит от приложения. Но все так просто, там должна быть серия сообщений.